# Incorrect judge ruling

Tags: rules

I was in SB and about 5 others limp in preflop. Flop come up and checks around the table to the dealer button player who raised the minimum. I call along with one other. Turn comes up and same thing- dealer button bets minimum and I call while the other player folds. River comes up, I make a straight and check and DB only says “I bet” while tossing chips out while Neither dealer or player announces amount. I say call and push chips out thinking it was the minimum amount, dealer says show so I show a Straight vs KK. Dealer says I win and starts pushing chips my way, DB says nice hand and helps with chips then someone on other side of table (who was never in the hand) says I never called right amount. DB says he bet 5x the BB but I only called 2x. Tournament judge comes over and rules the whole pot plus whatever I had to get to right amount goes to DB player. I admit I didn’t call the right amount but shouldn’t it have just been a warning since the hand was technically over and myself along with the dealer and DB player all missed it?

Comment: Grinch was dead on with his answer. That ruling was so bad it is suspicious. I do not know the stakes, but if it was a lot I would consider taking it up with local gaming board or authority. And at any rate I would take it above the floor persons head and complain in writing.

Comment: Yes, this is so bad it has to be that you are not describing the situation correctly. You also don't mention whether this is a limit or no-limit game, which is necessary information.

Comment: It was a small local no limit tournament and I probably should’ve added at the time I had a less than positive reputation at the free poker leagues for not liking a lot of the other players

Comment: @RichardMehrer Was it a casino tournament, or home or bar tournament?

Comment: It was a bar tournament hosted by local Fire Dept.

Comment: You just got hit with a naive ruling by someone whom had less then a full grasp of the rules. The ruling was wrong, but here there is not much to do about it, besides maybe showing the guy whom made the ruling this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you said call and pushed chips out. You absolutely called. Very wrong ruling. It's extremely common to see people call bets by just putting a single chip out.

When you say the words "I call", there is no ifs or buts regardless of chips placed on the table that you have called whatever the bet is.